# Can't record higher framerate in recordRTC

Tags: javascript, angular, webrtc, webm, recordrtc

Can't record higher than 30 fps using recordRTC to webm. Camera is capable of recording at 60 fps at the desired resolution at 1920x1080. Any ideas on how to fully record the 60 fps?

```
    var options = {
      mimeType: 'video/webm',
      video: {
          width: 1920,
          height: 1080
       },
      bitsPerSecond: 51200000,
      frameRate: 60
    };
  this.stream = stream;
  this.recordRTC = RecordRTC(stream, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC.js"></script>
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>

<button id="btn-record">Click To Record</button>
<hr>
<video id="your-video" autoplay playsinline controls style="width: 50%; border-adius: 9px;"></video>
<script>
var recorder;
var yourVideo = document.getElementById('your-video');
document.getElementById('btn-record').onclick = function() {
    this.disabled = true;
    this.style.background = 'transparent';
    this.style.color = 'grey';

    var cameraProperties = {
        video: {
            width: 1920,
            height: 1080
        },
        audio: true
    };

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(cameraProperties)
        .then(function(cameraStream) {
            yourVideo.volume = 0;
            yourVideo.srcObject = cameraStream;

            recorder = RecordRTC(cameraStream, {
                videoBitsPerSecond: 51200000,
                mimeType: 'video/webm'
            });
            recorder.startRecording();

            setTimeout(function() {
                recorder.stopRecording(function() {
                    var blob = recorder.getBlob();
                    alert('Recording size: ' + bytesToSize(blob.size));

                    var videoURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    yourVideo.srcObject = null;
                    yourVideo.volume = 1;
                    yourVideo.src = videoURL;
                });
            }, 5000);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error('Unable to capture 1080p', error);
            alert('Maybe 1080p is not supported by your camera. Please check yoru console logs.');
        });
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank Mauz, unfortunately I already am able to record at 1080p, I am just trying to record at 60 framerate, i set the recording options to 60, but the output video is only 30 frames per second

Comment: Did you set {cameraProperties}.frameRate{exact:66}?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I did try setting the framerate to be exact, however I am seeing 30fps output. I have verified my camera can output to 60fps via OBS